# Can't add user- wrong message "this user name is invalid because it uses illegal characters"

Tags: users

I am working on a webpage for a client and we have encounter a weird issue. When I use the clients login and add users to the website It works perfectly.

But when the client uses the same logins they get the wrong message "this user name is invalid because it uses illegal characters. Please enter a valid username".

What could go wrong here? Is there a setting on the clients computer?
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the username so it is possible there are illegal characters in the name. I would check that first.

To give a possible solution, please check this answer as it seems to be the same question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/189172/168537